# Are friendly URLs based on directories?

Tags: url, directory, friendly-url

I've been reading many articles about SEO and investigating how to improve my site. I found an article that said that having friendly URLs help online indexers to find and positionate your site better than using URLs with lots of GET parameters so I decided to adapt my site to this kind of URL. I've also read that there's a way (editing .htaccess) but it's not the best way and it doesn't look really good.

For example, that's how Google's *About* URL looks like:

```
https://www.google.com/search/about/es/
```

When surfing into FTP do they see the directories `search/about/es/index.html`? If so, you must create many files and directories for each language instead of using `&l=es`, is it that worth?

Answer (score 0):

You can never know (for sure) how resources are mapped to URLs.

For example, the URL `https://www.google.com/search/about/es/` could

- point to the HTML file `/search/about/es/index.html`
- point to the HTML file `/foo/bar/1.html`
- point to the PHP script `/index.php`
- point to the PHP script `/search.php?title=about&lang=es`
- point to the document available from the URL `https://internal.google.com/1238`
- …

It’s always the server that, given the URL from the request, decides which resource to deliver. Unless you have access to the server, you can’t know how. (Even if a URL ends with `.php`, it’s not necessarily the case that PHP is involved at all.)

The server could look for a file that physically exists (if URL rewriting is involved: even in "other" places than what the URL path suggests), the server could run a script that generates a document on the fly (e.g., taking the content from your database), the server could output the file available from another URL, etc.

Related Wikipedia articles:

- [Rewrite engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)
- [Web framework: URL mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework#URL_mapping)
- [Front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller)