# Web page without real files corresponding to URLs?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, url-routing

geniuses!

I need to make a demo page acting like DBpedia (http://dbpedia.org).

Two pages from different URLs,

http://dbpedia.org/page/Barack_Obama and 
http://dbpedia.org/page/Lionel_Messi,

show different content.

I cannot really think DBpedia has million pages for all individual entities (E.g., Barack Obama and Lionel Messi).

How can I handle such URL request?

I know a bit about GET request but example URLs above do not seem like to use GET method.

Thank you in advance!

ps. Please teach me the process. Something like:
 
1. A user enters URL on a browser.
2. ...

Comment: It's still can be simple GET request. And in your example it is a GET request. At the server-side you handle request like this (for example): `/page/{question}` where question - it is a path veriable . Than server take this path variable, get relevant data with its magic methods, generate page and return it to you. Process of handeling path variables dependes on your server-side language and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

When visiting http://dbpedia.org/page/Barack_Obama, your browser *does* send a GET request, e.g.:

```
GET /page/Barack_Obama HTTP/1.1
Host: dbpedia.org
```

The server (dbpedia.org) receives this GET request and then decides what to do. **From the outside, you can’t know (for sure) *how* the server does something.** The two common cases are:

- [Static web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page): a file gets served that exists somewhere on the server. The URL path is often mapped to the server’s file system, but that’s [not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36595114/1591669) the case.
- [Dynamic web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page): a file gets served that is generated on the fly. The content often comes from a database, but that’s not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some solutions, I'm now using Spring Web MVC framework.

Maybe Dynamic web page solution mentioned in unor's answer.

```
@Controller 
public class SimpleDisplayController {

    @RequestMapping("/page/{symbolicName:[!-z]+}")
    public String displayEntity(HttpServletRequest hsr, Model model) {

        String reqPath = (String) hsr.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
        String entityLb = reqPath.substring(reqPath.lastIndexOf("/"));        

        model.addAttribute("label", entityLb);

        return "entity";

    }

}
```

I could get request using regex as you can see at the 4th line: **@RequestMapping("/page/{symbolicName:[!-z]+}")**.

The function above returns the string 'entity' which is the name of a HTML file serving as a template.

The following code is a body part of the example HTML template.

```
<body>
    <p th:text="'About entity ' + ${label} + '...'" />
</body>
```

Since I add an attribute with the key 'label' in the controller above, the template can process ${label}.

In the example HTML template, th:text is a snytax of Thymeleaf (Java library to make an XML/XHTML/HTML5 template) which is supported by Spring.